# getting "0" from an ajax request

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a drop down menu with taxonomy terms (thrid level terms), and when a term is selected I want to show its parent term through an ajax request. But for some reason I get the value of "0" instead of parent term value. Can someone help and check my code and see what I'm missing here:

```
$("select#districts").change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/metrics/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {action: 'county_request', term_id : $(this).children(":selected").prop("value")},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
                $('#district-county').html(data);
            }
        });
});
```

// get parent terms

```
function ajax_handle_request(){
    $output = ajax_get_parent_term_by_id($_REQUEST['term_id']);
    return $output;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_county_request', 'ajax_handle_request');
add_action('wp_ajax_county_request', 'ajax_handle_request');

function ajax_get_parent_term_by_id($term_id){
    $parent_term  = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id->parent, 'state');
    return $parent_term;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to output the results and then do `die()` or `exit()` in order to terminate script execution. With this in mind, your code should look like that:

```
// get parent terms

function ajax_handle_request(){
    $output = ajax_get_parent_term_by_id($_REQUEST['term_id']);
    echo $output && ! is_wp_error( $output ) ? $output->name : '';
    exit();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_county_request', 'ajax_handle_request');
add_action('wp_ajax_county_request', 'ajax_handle_request');

function ajax_get_parent_term_by_id($term_id){
    $parent_term  = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id->parent, 'state');
    return $parent_term;
}
```

This will return a the name of the requested term. If you want to display something else in `#district-county`, just change the `echo $output && ! is_wp_error( $output ) ? $output->name : '';` to whatever you want to display.

Comment: thanks for looking at this. I tried your code but it doesn't return any value. I change the "echo" line to just "return $output", and it returns "0" as before.. any idea?

Comment: The thing is that at the very bottom of `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` you have `die( '0' );` which is actually the thing that gives you a "0". When you do `return ...` the value is returned, and since your function is called from an action hook, the returned value doesn't get displayed or anything. Please try adding `var_dump($output);` before your `return ...` line and give me the output of that.

Comment: thanks Nikola, I have fixed the problem.. I have just updated the code below.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the ajax_get_parent_term_by_id function doesn't return a value, I changed it to the following and now it works:

```
function ajax_get_parent_term_by_id($term_id){
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, 'taxonomy' );
    $parent_term = get_term($term->parent, 'taxonomy' );
    return $parent_term;
}
```

Comment: I can't, it says: "You can accept your own answer in 23 hours"